# Get the matched URI in a kong plugin

Tags: kong, kong-plugin

I am writing a Kong plugin (v. 0.13) and wondering where / how it is possible to find the matched URI from an API. For example, with the following `uris` value set:

```
uris: ["/endpoint/[\da-f]{8}"]
```

The API will be matched on any 8 digit hex number after `/endpoint`. So within a plugin, how can I access the URI that was matched? I've tried `kong.request.get_path()` or `ngx.req.get_path()`, but both of those return nil values / throw errors. Ideally, if the `uris` parameters contain `/[0-9a-z?=]` I'd like to match the whole URI in a single field, including any query parameters (i.e. everything after the host and port components of the URI).

I am using the 0.14 plugin doc to try figure out what to do. Upgrading is not an option right now.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `kong` wasn't available on 0.13 and I had to `ngx.var.uri` to match the URI. This excludes the args / query parameters from matching though.

Comment: Although - is it possible to get the configuration of an API that an `access` plugin is configured for? e.g. Is strip_api enabled?